# Would an internship at a private company in India make me competitive for post-docs in the US?

Tags: postdocs, career-path, industry, early-career, engineering

I am on the verge (4-5 months) of completing my PhD in micro-scale heat transfer engineering in India. My long-term goal is to get a post-doc in the US or Europe and remain in academia long term.

I have two offers for my next step:

- A 1-year post-doc at an Indian university
- A 3-month internship at the heat transfer research division of an multi-national corporation

My question is: **to what extent would the internship help me become competitive for US/European post-docs?** Is this sort of industry experience valuable, compared to a more traditional post-doc?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. Three month vs. one year. Ask yourself, what can you accomplish in 3 months? It'll take one week for you to get used to the environment. You can do almost nothing in the last week because you need to wrap up. So, only 10 weeks left if you choose to do the 3 month thing, regardless it's postdoc or an internship at a company. You do not have a dilemma.

Comment: The only advantage (to you) is that you can list experience working for MNC for 3 months. Frankly, no one cares. What everybody cares in Academia is what research you have accomplished. 3 month at an MNC is useful **only** if you want to work in industry because you'll have 3 month experience. Experience really counts in industry.

Comment: @Nobody Your comments have been very helpful. I now have a much clearer picture. In a way, you have answered the question. So if you post an answer, I am ready to accept it if this question is opened.